# How to add more than one beacon in a single region?

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, estimote, android-ibeacon

According to [Estimote](https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203776266-What-is-a-beacon-region-):

> There is almost no limit to how many beacons can be included in a single region (technically, it’s over 4 billion).

How do we add more than one beacon in one single region for monitoring?

We create a region like this:

```
UUID ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-4568-AFF9-25556B57FE6D");
Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId", ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [an Estimote community manager](https://twitter.com/Esti_Wojtek/status/678888108708859905):

> If a region is defined by UUID or UUID + Major, then every beacons with this UUID (or UUID + Major) is included

Which means if i have two beacons with same `UUID` and `Major` and if i created `Region` then all the beacons belongs to that **Region** should be discovered.

### Example:

```
UUID ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D");
Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId", major, null, null);
```