# Kotakt.io Beacon - Best way to identify/get/scan only your own beacons?

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, kontakt.io

For [Kontakt.io](https://kontakt.io/) and Specially for "iBeacon", I have been looking for ways to identify and get my own beacons which I would provide to my users.

I need to get solution for both Android and iOS.

With my initial search I have some results for Android as,

This Sample class demonstrate that [we can use and apply filters](https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-beacon-admin-sample-app/blob/master/sample-app/src/main/java/com/kontakt/sample/samples/ScanFiltersActivity.java).

Also this one suggests on [iBeacon profile identifiers – best practise](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201694581-iBeacon-profile-identifiers-best-practise)

---

My Concerns are,

For applying filter, I need to know particular range of ids and what If I want to go beyond that, I will have to change my code to include that range every time?

Is there any sample/guide for iOS to apply filter ?

If anyone has done this, what approach you have used to scan & get only your own devices ?

Please provide me guide/demo/suggestion for iOS and Android both.

Comment: Do you know about `region` in beacon ? `Estimote` provide this. I don't know about `Kontakt`

Comment: I have read that many times during my searches but still confused regarding, How to create/apply region in Panel and how to use them in application code ?

Comment: It's very easy. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393612/how-to-add-more-than-one-beacon-in-a-single-region)

Comment: @MD  i have search beacons with regions in IOS but in that way, we are not able to receive UniqueID of that beacon.

Comment: @MiralDhokiya Sorry don't know about `iOS`

Comment: @MD Following that link, I will need to write down my own UUID in the CODE, I am looking out for solutions where I don't need to mention UUID/Minor/Major in my code.  Or any other parameter other than this 3 which can be used for Filtering beacon.

Comment: @MKJParekh Than just pass `NULL` value to each parameter. That identify all the `beacons`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to play with Kontakt.io API or Kontakt.io Security.

Region basically is the area around beacon (where you can receive its packets).

If you do not want to place those values like Unique ID and Minor / Major / UUID than try [Kontakt.io Secure](https://kontakt.io/blog/answering-your-questions-about-kontakt-io-secure/).

In android it is easy, you need to place default UUID and the iBeacon [Listener](http://kontaktio.github.io/kontakt-android-sdk/3.2.0/Javadoc/) basically solves the security in the backend for you.

Regarding the play with API, you can fetch the values from the cloud and than use them as variables in the application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have checked that links but still confused as I didn't see and implementation example for how to detect beacons else than what is shown here - https://developer.kontakt.io/android-sdk/3.2.0/quickstart/        - I am now getting feeling that I will have to register all my beacons in web panel and then assign same UUID and again will have to keep that UUID in my code to scan on it.I am afraid This way anyone would be able to fetch my code and see UUID.

Comment: check my GitHub channel
https://github.com/konradkontakt

You cannot deal with it without assigning them to your account. You will need your's API key. Using this key you will be able to solve the shuffled values of the UUID and Major and Minor while in app you will filter by not shuffled values.